# Integrate $ \int_0^{\infty} \! x^2 e^{-ax^2} \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $$ \int_0^{\infty} \! x^2 e^{-ax^2} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

We may assume without proof:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \! e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Comment: use integration by part $$ xe^{-ax^2}dx=du $$

Comment: Any restriction on $a$, like $a>0$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\displaystyle -\frac{\partial \ }{\partial a} e^{-ax^2} = x^2 e^{-ax^2}$, thus

$$\frac{d \ }{da} \int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} dx = \int_0^\infty  \frac{\partial \ }{\partial a} e^{-ax^2} dx = - \int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-ax^2} dx$$

Now evaluate the first integral and afterwards differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

First solve by simple substitution the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} dx$
and the differentiate that result twice with respect to $a$. The answer
is a special case of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2m} e^{-\beta x^{2m}}dx
= \Gamma(v)/(n\beta^v)$ with $v\equiv (2m+1)/(2n)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $a>0$, integration by parts:

$$ \int_0^\infty x^2{\rm e}^{-ax^2} dx = \int_0^\infty x\left((-2a)^{-1}{\rm e}^{-ax^2}\right)'dx $$
$$ = x (-2a)^{-1}{\rm e}^{-ax^2} \mid_0^\infty- \int_0^\infty (-2a)^{-1}{\rm e}^{-ax^2} dx $$

then change of variable $y = a^{1/2}x$ in the last integral:

$$    = x (-2a)^{-1}{\rm e}^{-ax^2} \mid_0^\infty- \int_0^\infty (-2a)^{-1}{\rm e}^{-y^2} a^{-1/2}dy. $$